# Django Template filter is passing wrong data

Tags: django, filter

I'm collecting data in multiple nested dicts and passing them to my template. I wrote a simple filter to get the data from the dict by key:

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

In my template I'm accessing the data:

```
{% for location_type_id, location_type_name in location_types.items %}
    {% with disctrict=disctricts|get_item:location_type_id %}
        ...
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I'm using {{ debug }} I see:

```
{'districts': {5: {6: 'Friedrichshain'}, 7: {7: 'Kreuzberg', 8: 'Charlottenburg'}},
'location_types': {5: 'Bar', 7: '5'}}
```

But I get the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'. When printing the arguments of the filter I get an empty string passed to filter instead of a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your template, which probably causes the error:
`{% with disctrict=disctricts|get_item:location_type_id %}` should be `{% with disctrict=districts|get_item:location_type_id %}`

Comment: Saved me! I was sitting there for hours staring at the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. The variable name is `districts` but you are using `disctricts` in the template.